# Oracle SQL Developer. Find referenced views of synonyms

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello in the **PL/SQL Developer** beneath the category synonyms there is a tab (referenced by), which displays referenced views of a synonym.

On my system there is no PL/SQL Developer installed. So is there any function in the normal **Oracle SQL Developer** or a query how I can retrieve the same information as in the **PL/SQL Developer** ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you ...

```
select o1.owner,o1.object_name, o2.owner,o2.object_name 
  from PUBLIC_DEPENDENCY t, Dba_Objects o1, Dba_Objects o2
 WHERE t.object_id=o1.object_id
   AND t.referenced_object_id=o2.object_id
   AND o1.object_name="your_object_name"
```

Comment: this is not working for me. To make clear: I'm having a synonym and want to get the name of views that are dependant of this synonym.

Comment: it is a general dependency query. do you use your object name in upper case? can u find your synonym in dba_objects?

Comment: I don't have a Dba_Objects table

Comment: You should be able to use the `USER_OBJECTS` view instead of `DBA_OBJECTS`, so long as the view is in the current schema.

Comment: Or ALL_OBJECTS if it is not in your schema but you have privileges on the view.